# Prometheus - Create a new label from file_sd_configs filename?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

We have our file_sd_config filenames with our sites as the last 4 characters before the file extension:

```
raritan_pdus_laxa.json
raritan_pdus_laxb.json
raritan_pdus_laxc.json
```

Yet I cannot extract the site into a new label and get no errors or warnings to let me know what I am doing incorrectly:

```
relabel_configs:
  ...
  - source_labels: ['__meta_filepath']
    regex: '(\w{4})(\.[^.]+).*'
    replacement: '$1'
    target_label: 'site_label'
```

I see some examples with single quotes and some without, but neither combination seems to be my issue.  And I believe the regex is perl correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus regexes are fully anchored, so try:

```
 regex: '.*_(\w{4})\.json'
```

so that the start of the filename is also matched.

Comment: That certainly was the issue.  Thanks Brian!